# list.__delslice__ python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, python-2.x

Is there a method for list that does what the python 2 `list.__delslice__` does? There is a `__delitem__` but it seems it only deletes one item instead of from x to y so here is an example of what I want to do

```
somelist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
somelist.__delslice__(4, len(somelist))
print(somelist)
# output: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It seems they may have removed this from python 3, did they? If not what is it now called or is there a module that has it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Python 2.7 - `object.__delslice__` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delslice__):

> Called to implement deletion of self[i:j]. Same notes for i and j as
>   for __getslice__(). **This method is deprecated. If no __delslice__() is
>   found, or for extended slicing of the form self[i:j:k], a slice object
>   is created, and passed to __delitem__()**, instead of __delslice__()
>   being called.

So, call the `__delitem__` with `slice` object:

```
>>> somelist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> somelist.__delitem__(slice(4, len(somelist)))
>>> somelist
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

BTW, you can use `None` in place of `len(somelist)`:

```
>>> somelist.__delitem__(slice(2, None))
>>> somelist
[1, 2]
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can use `del` statement with slice:

```
del somelist[2:]
```

Comment: I'd use `None` there, but yes.

Comment: instead of using `somelist.__delitem__(slice(4, len(somelist)))` should used `del somelist[4: len(somelist)]` or better `del somelist[4:]`

Comment: @A.Sommerh, I updated answer to include it. Thank you for the comment.